# select onclick that contains _blank

Tags: jquery, onclick

i select links with a blank target to set a title attribute

```
jQuery('a[target~="_blank"]').attr('title', 'New window');
```

that works.

But when i select the onclick attribute that doesn't work

```
jQuery('a[onclick~="_blank"]').attr('title', 'New window');
```

any clues?

the link looks like that:

```
<a onclick="javascript:this.target=&quot;_blank&quot;" title="" href="http://link.com">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code :

```
jQuery('a[onclick*="_blank"]').attr('title', 'New window');
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me using the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) -

```
$("a[onclick*='_blank']")
```

Could you use that instead?

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/uZaCW/

Answer (score 0):

found that contains is * and not ~

```
jQuery("a[onclick*='_blank']").attr('alt', 'New window');
```